# React form handleChange is not updating state

Tags: react-redux

Form input onChange is not updating state. The action and reducer fire properly and backend rails API is updated, but the state does not change and nothing renders in the DOM.

I have used console logs to ensure that the action and reducer are working properly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


class TaskInput extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    }
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.addTask({name: this.state.name}, this.props.goal.id)
    this.setState({
      name: ''
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form className="new-task-form" onSubmit={(e) =>this.handleSubmit(e)}>
       <Form.Field>
         <label className="form-label">Add Task</label>
         <input id="name" required value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
       </Form.Field>
       <Button basic color='purple' type="submit">Add Task</Button>
       <hr/>
     </Form>
    )
  }
}

export default connect()(TaskInput)




import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { addTask, deleteTask } from '../actions/tasksActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchGoal } from '../actions/goalsActions'
import Tasks from '../components/Tasks/Tasks';
import TaskInput from '../components/Tasks/TaskInput';

class TasksContainer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchGoal(this.props.goal.id)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <TaskInput
          goal={this.props.goal}
          addTask={this.props.addTask}
          />

        <strong>Tasks:</strong>
        <Tasks
          key={this.props.goal.id}
          tasks={this.props.goal.tasks}
          deleteTask={this.props.deleteTask}
        />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tasks: state.tasksData
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addTask, deleteTask, fetchGoal })(TasksContainer);



export default function taskReducer(state = {
  loading: false,
  tasksData: []
},action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'FETCH_TASKS':
      return {...state, tasksData: action.payload.tasks}
    case 'LOADING_TASKS':
      return {...state, loading: true}
    case 'CREATE_TASK':
      console.log('CREATE Task', action.payload )
      return {...state, tasksData:[...state.tasksData, action.payload.task]}
    case 'DELETE_TASK':
      return {...state, loading: false, tasksData: state.tasksData.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload.id )}

    default:
      return state;
    }
}
```

handleSubmit calls the action to addTask. handleChange updates state and renders the new task in DOM. handleSubmit is working. handleChange is not.

Comment: But if `handleChange` wasn't working you wouldn't be able to change the field's value, right? And why export `connect()` with no mappings?

Comment: Ahh that is true..Now Im even more confused as to why nothing renders in the DOM if handleChange is working. I added connect just to see if it helped. Forgot to remove it before posting this.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're expecting that isn't happening? What do you mean by "state does not change and nothing renders in the DOM?" Are you running the [redux dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) and [react dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)?

Comment: Please note - I am very new to React/Redux. Just learning. I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that Im trying to render into a card?

Comment: Render into a card? Like a material-ui Card?

Comment: When I submit the task it should render on the page but nothing appears unless I refresh the page. The same thing with the delete action. I am using React dev tools,

Comment: Yes a material-ui Card

Comment: So is there a separate component that's rendering a list of Tasks? And that list isn't updating? If that's the case then what's probably happening is that the list doesn't know about the new task so it isn't re-rendering. A common cause of this is adding an item to an existing array in a reducer. If you do `tasks.push(newTask)`, then the redux state is still using the same array as before, so it doesn't trigger an update. The solution is to assign a _new array_, like `tasks: [...existingTasks, newTask]`.

Comment: Yes the parent is a Tasks Container. So in the reducer I have this:
```case 'CREATE_TASK':
      return {...state, tasksData:[...state.tasksData, action.payload.task]}```

Comment: That looks good. I think the TaskInput component in your question is probably fine. The question is why doesn't your list see the change. I assume the list is connect-ed to `state.tasksData`? Can you tell whether the list is getting the updated state? Can you console.log when it re-renders to see if it's updating? When does the new task get inserted into redux state? Is it when the server request succeeds?

Comment: It gets the updated state when I reload/refresh the page. Not until then.

Comment: So `this.props.addTask(…)` does an XHR request to add it server side? When does `CREATE_TASK` get dispatched? Is it basically `postToServer(...).then(dispatch(CREATE_TASK))`?

Comment: It gets dispatched when addTask is run ```export const addTask = ( task, id ) => {
  console.log('adding task')
  let data = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(task)
  }
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(`/api/goals/${id}/tasks`, data)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(task => {
// let result = {task, id}
        dispatch({
          type: 'CREATE_TASK',
          payload: task
        })
      })
      .catch(err => err)
  }
}```

Comment: I noticed the Tasks component is passed `tasks={this.props.goal.tasks}` as opposed to `tasks={this.props.tasks}`, the latter being the redux state mapping. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. They are associated - a goal has_many tasks

Comment: But does `goal` get updated with the new task? I don't see that in the reducer.

Comment: I have a separate goalsReducer

Comment: and they are combined

Comment: And there's a component above TasksContainer that gets the goal from redux state and passes it down as a prop? Have you verified that the goal state gets updated with the new task?

Comment: Does the TaskContainer need to get props from a parent? I currently have it being rendered inside of a Goal.js component (that is a child of GoalsContainer). I checked the goals state and again it only updates state once I reload/refresh the page.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand where TasksContainer gets the goals prop. Any chance you could put all of this up somewhere like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) where I can see it and/or we can look at it together? Is there a github repo?

Comment: I appreciate you helping me unravel it! Its getting the props from Goal.js (which is a child of another container). Here is the github repo: https://github.com/alisong779/a_golden_portfolio

Comment: Im thinking maybe i need to move the TasksContainer out of Goal.js...

Comment: I don't see where the goal gets updated with the new task. Is it there and I'm not seeing it?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. They are associated through AR in Rails and Im using the goal.id when creating tasks. Well is 3am where Im at and I need sleep. Hopefully I can catch up with you again tomorrow? If you see anything off please let me know. Im truly at a loss here.

Comment: I mean I don't see anything client-side that updates the goal to include the new task. If the goal isn't updated in the redux state, then component props don't change and react doesn't re-render, which would explain why you're not seeing the new task until you reload.

Comment: I'll check in again tomorrow. Let me know if you figure it out. G'night.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199786/discussion-on-question-by-alison-golden-react-form-handlechange-is-not-updating).

Comment: I cant use chat